# How to call eth.call a second time with the first call taking effect on the blockchain

Tags: web3js

eth.call:

> Executes a message call transaction, which is directly executed in the
> VM of the node, but never mined into the blockchain.

How can I call a second time, but after the first call takes effect on blockchain?

If it is not possible, what other alternatives exist to simulate two calls in this way?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of interactions with the nodes:

1. `call` used for functions that **does not** change the state of the EVM (does not cost gas)
2. `send` used for functions that **does** change the state of the EVM (cost gas)

You can't effect the blockchain with a `call`

**Edit:** Check [this article](https://bitsofco.de/calling-smart-contract-functions-using-web3-js-call-vs-send/) for further details

Comment: I know that call does not affect the blockchain, what I ask is how two transactions can be simulated in a row.

Comment: @user2983041 by simulating transaction from the sniped you are reffering to you should understand that it is simulated on your node and since it is not changing the state (because it is **call**) it doesn't have to be propagated to the other nodes. So basically there is no difference what so ever if you are going to simulate it once, twice or 1000 times the result will be the same every time.

Comment: Sure, I understand that perfectly. What I have said in the question is that if it cannot be done with call, with what other method can two calls be executed so that the second one takes the chain of blocks manipulated by the first. I know it can be done because there are paid services that do it.

Answer (score 0):

The exact scenario would be clearer if you post some details about the calls.

However, I see 2 scenarios here

1. Call one and call two are independent of each other.
   Since you want to call two functions, you do not have to wait for the first function to produce the result before starting the second. The first function will not alter anything on the blockchain since it is a call (as opposed to a send). So the result of the second function will theoretically not depend on the first function.
2. Call two uses the output of call one as input
   In this case you could await the first function and then call the second.

```
    const result1 = await myContract.methods.function1().call();
    const result2 = await myContract.function2(result1).call();
```

You can refer to this link to now more about call and send.
[web3 contract calls](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html)

Comment: To explain it in another way. I need that if the first call makes a token swap to a wallet in the second call it can detect that the balance of that wallet has changed. Answer 2 are independent simulations, therefore it is not what I need.